# Regarding MarkLogic Upgrade from 9 to 10

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-9, marklogic-10

As per MarkLogic documentation([https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/relnotes/chap4#id_72376"](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/relnotes/chap4#id_72376%22))

"*MarkLogic Corporation strongly recommends performing a backup of your databases before upgrading to MarkLogic 10. Additionally, **MarkLogic Corporation recommends that you first upgrade to the latest maintenance release of MarkLogic 7 or MarkLogic 8 before upgrading to MarkLogic 10**.*"

Does the above line applicable for MarkLogic 9 also? Do we need to upgrade to latest maintenance release of MarkLogic 9 before upgrading the cluster to MarkLogic 10?
We are currently using ML 9.0-11.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is not a requirement, but it is a recommendation.  As always it's best to test out procedures prior to upgrading to avoid any unexpected problems.

Comment: Thank you. If it's a recommendation, we are going to follow it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the above lines is applicable for MarkLogic 9, also. It's always the best and recommended practice to upgrade to the latest minor version before upgrading to next major version.